# Equivalente em C# (pacote Microsoft.Data.Analysis) do Python usando pandas.DataFrame.replace

Tags: c#, python, pandas

Em Python usando o Pandas, para substituir determinados valores de um dataframe eu simplimente usava a função `pandas.DataFrame.replace`, como no fragmento de código abaixo:

```
dados1['RACA'] = dados1['RACA'].replace({0:"nao_declarado", 1:"branca", 2:"preta", 3:"parda", 4:"amarela", 5:"indigena"})
```

Contudo, em C# não encontrei um método no pacote `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` para fazer algo pareceido. A forma encontrada para fazer a substituição foi com a criação de um dataframe auxiliar, fazer um merge com o dataframe original e eliminar as colunas desnecessárias, como no código abaixo:

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;

DataFrame df2 = DataFrame.LoadCsv(@"docs\microdados_enem_2019_sp_reduzido.csv", separator: ';', encoding:Encoding.Latin1);
df2["TP_COR_RACA"].SetName("ID_RACA");

// Cria dataframe auxiliar
var ids = new List<Single>() {0,1,2,3,4,5};
var nomesRaca = new List<string>() {"nao_declarado", "branca", "preta", "parda", "amarela", "indigena"};

var idColumn = new SingleDataFrameColumn("Id", ids);
var nomesRacaColumn = new StringDataFrameColumn("RACA", nomesRaca);
var dataFrame2 = new DataFrame(idColumn, nomesRacaColumn);

// Fazer o merge
df2 = df2.Merge(dataFrame2, new string[] {"ID_RACA"}, new string[] {"Id"});

// Elimina as colunas desnecessárias
df2.Columns.Remove("ID_RACA");
df2.Columns.Remove("Id");

// Output para conferências
Console.WriteLine(df2.Head(6));
```

Existe no pacote `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` uma forma mais eficiente de fazer essas substituições, como no `pandas.Dataframe.replace`?

Caso não haja essa funcionalidade, qual seria a forma mais eficiente de se fazer isso?

Os dados utilizados são os [Microdados do Enem 2019](https://www.gov.br/inep/pt-br/acesso-a-informacao/dados-abertos/microdados/enem).